# WordPress not showing the SVG stroke path

Tags: html, wordpress, svg, wordpress-theming, stroke-dasharray

```
<svg height="80" width="300">
<g fill="none" stroke="black" 
stroke-width="6">
<path stroke-linecap="butt" d="M5 20 
 l215 0" />
<path stroke-linecap="round" d="M5 
40 l215 0" />
<path stroke-linecap="square" d="M5 
60 l215 0" />
</g>
</svg>
```

Ok so I wrote this code in my WordPress post and nothing showed up. But there's no problem when I run it in a simple HTML file format . Can anyone tell why this thing is not working in WordPress...

Comment: TinyMCE strips SVG code. It can't be added through the Text editor.

Comment: Then how should I add this type in my WordPress post ?

Comment: Follow this article: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/wordpress/allow-svg-through-wordpress-media-uploader/ to add the SVG mime-type to WP and then you can save your svg code as a .svg file and upload/insert it like a regular image.